# Schroders Big number sequence

Tags: recursion, math, ocaml, largenumber

I am implementing a recursive program to calculate the certain values in the Schroder sequence, and I'm having two problems:

1. I need to calculate the number of calls in the program;
2. Past a certain number, the program will generate incorrect values (I think it's because the number is too big);

Here is the code:

```
let rec schroder n = 
  if n <= 0 then 1
  else if n = 1 then 2
  else 3 * schroder (n-1) + sum n 1 
and sum n k = 
  if (k > n-2) then 0 
  else schroder k * schroder (n-k-1) + sum n (k+1)
```

When I try to return tuples (**1.**), the function `sum` stops working because it's trying to return `int` when it has type `int * int`;
Regarding **2.**, when I do `schroder 15` it returns:
`-357364258`
when it should be returning
`3937603038`.

EDIT:

firstly thanks for the tips, secondly after some hours of deep struggle, i manage to create the function, now my problem is that i'm struggling to install zarith. I think I got it installed, but ..

1. in terminal when i do `ocamlc -I +zarith test.ml` i get an error saying `Required module 'Z' is unavailable`.
2. in utop after doing `#load "zarith.cma";;` and `#install_printer Z.pp_print;;` i can compile, run the function and it works. However i'm trying to implement a `Scanf.scanf` so that i can print different values of the sequence. With this being said whenever i try to run the scanf, i dont get a chance to write any number as i get a message saying that `'\\n' is not a decimal digit`.

With this being said i will most probably also have problems with printing the value, because i dont think that i'm going to be able to print such a big number with a `%d`. The `let r1,c1 =` in the following code, is a example of what i'm talking about.

Here's what i'm using :

```
(function)
..
let v1, v2 = Scanf.scanf "%d %d" (fun v1 v2-> v1,v2);;

let r1,c1 = schroder_a (Big_int_Z.of_int v1) in
Printf.printf "%d %d\n" (Big_int_Z.int_of_big_int r1) (Big_int_Z.int_of_big_int c1);

let r2,c2 = schroder_a v2 in
Printf.printf "%d %d\n" r2 c2;
```

P.S. 'r1' & 'r2' stands for result, and 'c1' and 'c2' stands for the number of calls of schroder's recursive function.

P.S.S. the prints are written differently because i was just testing, but i cant even pass through the scanf so..

Comment: Please ask only one question per post

Comment: Also you should format your code properly, not have one toplevel definition dangling off the end of another.

Comment: Quick reply to the post, idk why, but my problem with the **scanf** in **utop** is that, if i try to do it more than once, i would get `'\\n' is not a decimal digit`, so.. basically if i wanted to get my code tested, i would need to exit **utop**, reenter **utop**, and load **zarith** and **Z.pp_print** as mentioned above.
As for the function, i did 2 versions where one would calculate to the 35th number of the sequence, that do **not require zarith**, and other that require it, but as the size of the number grows too quick i used a **hashtbl**
P.S. zarith have a funtion to print his numbers

Answer (score 2):

This is the third time I've seen this problem here on StackOverflow, so I assume it's some kind of school assignment. As such, I'm just going to make some comments.

1. OCaml doesn't have a function named `sum` built in. If it's a function you've written yourself, the obvious suggestion would be to rewrite it so that it knows how to add up the tuples that you want to return. That would be one approach, at any rate.
2. It's true, ints in OCaml are subject to overflow. If you want to calculate larger values you need to use a "big number" package. The one to use with a modern OCaml is [Zarith](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zarith/) (I have linked to the description on ocaml.org).

However, none of the other people solving this assignment have mentioned overflow as a problem. It could be that you're OK if you just solve for representable OCaml int values.

Answer (score 2):

`3937603038` is larger than what a 32-bit `int` can hold, and will therefore overflow. You can fix this by using `int64` instead (until you overflow that too). You'll have to use `int64` literals, using the `L` suffix, and operations from the `Int64` module. Here's your code converted to compute the value as an `int64`:

```
let rec schroder n = 
  if n <= 0 then 1L
  else if n = 1 then 2L
  else Int64.add (Int64.mul 3L (schroder (n-1))) (sum n 1)

and sum n k =
  if (k > n-2) then 0L
  else Int64.add (Int64.mul (schroder k) (schroder (n-k-1))) (sum n (k+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to calculate the number of calls in the program;
> ...
> the function 'sum' stops working because it's trying to return 'int' when it has type 'int * int'

Make sure that you have updated all the recursive calls to `shroder`. Remember it is now returning a pair not a number, so you can't, for example, just to add it and you need to unpack the pair first. E.g.,

```
...
else 
  let r,i = schroder (n-1) (i+1) in
  3 * r + sum n 1 and ...
```

and so on.

> Past a certain number, the program will generate incorrect values (I think it's because the number is too big);

You need to use an arbitrary-precision numbers, e.g., [zarith](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/zarith/)